# Scanning barcodes into Textbox, looking for duplicates with Javascript, still submits if duplicate is in last textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple HTML/PHP form to collect serial numbers via barcodes for shipments.  In this case I'm scanning 5 barcodes.  I'm using Javascript to check for duplicates (yes, I'm new to Javascript).  For any texboxes, except the last one, when I've entered a duplicate, I get the alert. Then I can acknowledge it and rescan the barcode that I duplicated. Then I continue on scanning the next barcodes.  On the last serial number, the duplicate is caught and the alert is sent.  When I acknowledge the alert, the form is still submitted. How do I prevent the form from submitting, so I can rescan the last barcode?

```
<?php
$serial[0] = array(
    'qty' => 2,
    'partno' => 'Test2'
);
$serial[1] = array(
    'qty' => 3,
    'partno' => 'Test4'
);
?>
<form method="post">
    <div id="sno" class="kdiv">
        <h2>Serial Number Entry</h2>     
        <?php $j = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach ($serial as $key => $row) : ?>   
         <table id="t02">
            <tr>
                <th>Part #</th>
                <th>Serial # Shipped</th>
            </tr> 
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $row['qty']; $i++) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php htmlout($row['partno']); ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="sno" type="text" 
                         name="serial[<?php htmlout($key); ?>]
                         [<?php htmlout($i) ?>]" 
                         <?php if ($j == 0) {echo 'autofocus';}?>/></td>    
                </tr>
                <?php $j++; ?>
            <?php endfor; ?>

        </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php htmlout($button1); ?>" name="<?php htmlout($action1); ?>"/>            
    </div>                        
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
var currentBoxNumber = 0;
var previousBoxNumber = 0; //
var serialentered = []; //

$("#sno").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        textboxes = $("input.sno");
        currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(event.target);
        //console.log(textboxes.index(this));
        if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
            nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
            nextBox.focus();
            nextBox.select();
            event.preventDefault();
            if (serialentered.indexOf(textboxes[currentBoxNumber].value) > -1) {
                alert("In TEST stmt, duplicate found!");
                textboxes[currentBoxNumber].focus();
                textboxes[currentBoxNumber].select();
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropogation();  // This is not working On the Last Bar Code Scan!!!!
            }
            serialentered.push(textboxes[currentBoxNumber].value);
            //alert(serialentered);  // Diagnostics only

            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is in this line

```
if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
```

In this line you are checking if you are on the last index of your array or not, if not, then you go in the `if` and do all the checking and coding, but if you are on the last index of the array(last input box), then you do not go in the `if` block and nothing is checked and the form submits!

But you have different issues in different parts of your code.

1- You have to check the `form submission event` if not then for example clicking on the `submit button` will submit the form without triggering the function.

2- The process of inserting values in the `serialentered array` is not correct and can cause multiple duplicate values in the array that really does not exist.

So, best practice is to keep some of the functionality of this function just for moving to the next `input element` by `enter key`. and then have another function to call it on `enter key` on the `input elements` and also call it on the `form submission event` to check duplicate records. if this function returns `false` then prevent the default action of the rest of these functions.

So the code will be something like this. But please do some stress tests on it to see if you can find any bugs in it and fix them accordingly if so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentBoxNumber = 0;
var serialentered = []; 

function fnChkDuplicateValues(currentElementIndex){
    textboxes = $("input.sno");
    serialentered = [];
    for(iCnt = 0, arrCnt = textboxes.length; iCnt < arrCnt; iCnt++){
        if(textboxes[iCnt].value.length !== 0)
            serialentered.push(textboxes[iCnt].value);
    }

    var arrSorted = serialentered.sort();

    for(var iCnt = 0, arrCnt = arrSorted.length; iCnt < arrCnt - 1; iCnt++){
        if(arrSorted[iCnt + 1] == arrSorted[iCnt]){
            alert("In TEST stmt, duplicate found!");
            if(currentElementIndex !== undefined){
                selectedBox = textboxes[currentElementIndex];
                selectedBox.focus();
                selectedBox.select();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sno").change(function(event){
        textboxes = $("input.sno");
        currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(event.target);
        if(textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null){
            nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1];
            nextBox.focus();
            nextBox.select();
        }
        return fnChkDuplicateValues(currentBoxNumber);
    });

    $("#frmSerial").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(fnChkDuplicateValues())
            $("#frmSerial")[0].submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Sorry, forgot to add this last line, you have to change this line `html` part as well:

```
<form method="post">
```

and change it to:

```
<form id="frmSerial" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful (and patient) response.  I was so sidetracked learning javascript that I missed basic logic.  I really appreciate the "best practices."  I ended up using part of your answer and part of my original logic to solve the issue.  (The barcode scanner ends each entry with a return, so it is used to move from one field to the next.) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. but please remember that pressing enter key in any form on any element, will trigger `form submit event`, so I think in your case you really do not need to listen for `enter key press event` on each element and just capturing `form submit event` will be enough...